# Different data sources for iPhone app in the App Store

Tags: iphone, web-services, localization, app-store

I'm going to release an app in the UK and US App Stores. I would like to have two different data sources according to the store my application is downloaded from. Basically I would like my app to connect to my US servers when downloaded from the US store and to the UK servers when downloaded from the british one. 
I was thinking of including the origin URL in the as localised string but I don't think this is a stable solution.

Any idea?

thanks a lot

Claus

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure, but I don't think the app has knowledge from where it was downloaded from.

You could create two apps, one for UK and one for US, and make the apps only available in their respective local App Stores.

However, depending on the amount of apps you would have to produce (if you intend to distribute your app in more than 2 countries in the future), it might be easier to just ask the user which data source to use on startup, or let him define one in the settings etc.
Or use the iPhone's current language or even location to select the data source.

Comment: I think the first solution you suggest is the best one as a US user might decide to switch on a European language messing things up

Comment: I'd be wary of splitting one app into two (or more) releases though. Your App Store rating might suffer as a result (you'll be splitting you downloads in two), and it might complicate your marketing (you'll get a different iTunes link per market).

Comment: If Clafou's points are relevant for you (they are absolutely valid!) I would emphasize the idea of selecting the data source by location of the phone. Of course that's not 100% "safe", but if one really intends to, he can mess up things anyway by simply forcing the other appstore in one way or another